# Ubuntu software app don't show install progress bar ( confused is installing or not!!)

Tags: software-installation, snap

My Ubuntu software app don't show install progress bar ( confused is installing or not!!) which has been show here:

[image]

So why this happened?

My OS info is:

```
 hostnamectl
   Static hostname: so-notebook
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: 34a2eb65afa64d60a60ed02d972e884d
           Boot ID: 9ee34ad4bff84b908e8719ab83029836
  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.0.0-37-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Thanks.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 the is a bug reported on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1742736